# Why don't we isolate electric train circuit from ground?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-circuits

We know that if we use an isolating transformer we can isolate a circuit from ground.So if i touch any of the two wires  touching with my feet the ground i will not get a shock.

Why dont we use that system in train rails and overhead lines so rails dont have to be grounded. If they are isolated from earth i would be able to touch both the rails and the ground without getting shocked even if they are not grounded

Comment: This is an engineering question.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. The purpose of an isolation transformer is to establish a ground reference for the circuit it is connected to, which cannot ever be connected to the hot side of the mains supply by sticking the power cord into the wall "backwards".

If you touch the high voltage output of a power supply that has an isolation transformer in it, you will still receive a shock (if you are standing on a grounded surface).

That transformer prevents you from getting a shock if you touched the metal enclosure of the power supply while the plug was in the wall in an orientation which connected the hot side of the AC mains to the enclosure.

Comment: Though when working on transformerless valve / tube TVs long ago, we used a 240V / 240V transformer as a safety precaution.

Comment: yes, the radios and guitar amplifiers that did not use the isolation trannies are called "death-o-matic" circuits today!